# How to remove highlighted background of text in vim?

Tags: vim, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am referring to the grey background highlighting which is making vim unreadable.
Note - I am running vim on Windows Subsystem for Linux. Also, this is not search highlighting. This is the default view every time I open Vim.

[image: screenshot]

It seems it has nothing to do with syntax highlighting. I created a new file named a.txt . On using :syn list , it said no syntax items defined for this buffer, but I still had grey background on every line. 
[image: screenshot of a.txt]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/ In the future, you might be better help here; although, it's still on topic here

Comment: Is this highlighting due to a search? If so, you can use `:nohl` to clear the search highlighting.  Have you tried changing your colorscheme? I'd also use Gvim. It has a wider gamut and many other benefits.

Comment: If it's not search highlighting, it seems to be a misguided color scheme; either in your `vim` configuration, or in your terminal preferences. I have never seen `vim` do this, though, so I can't give any more specific help.

Comment: No way to remove only background text highlighting in vim?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1706 Maybe this has some useful solutions. People running vim on WSL are going to be pretty rare, so you will likely have to do the legwork and solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my default colorscheme - 'evening' had been modified by the last windows update. A workaround is to change the colorscheme to different value - desert/elflord etc seem to be working fine. Note - this is not a solution just a workaround , as you can see there is still grey background highlighting in the top rows.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Comment: It seems it has nothing to do with syntax highlighting. I created a new file named a.txt . On using :syn list , it said no syntax items defined for this buffer, but I still had grey background on every line. ! (http://i.imgur.com/mIV5iG2.png )

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this problem now, here is how I was able to fix this issue.

I first realized that what was happening is that the highlight group Normal was not being set for some reason from my theme.
If, in the command line, I ran

```
:highlight Normal ctermfg=NONE
```

The highlighting would look normal.

The only problem being is that I had to run this after the buffer was entered, so traditional highlighting in the .vimrc was not working.

Adding

```
func! FixNormal()
    highlight Normal ctermfg=252
endfu
com! Normal call FixNormal()
```

Then above this function adding

```
au! BufEnter * Normal
```

The issue would resolve itself.

**Explanation**

The code creates a function that when called, does the same command that originally worked (highlighting Normal with None).
The function is then called by the autocommand (au!) when the buffer is entered (BufEnter) and runs the function Normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had grey text highlights that were caused by my current syntax highlighting file.

In this case, `:syntax off` did the trick

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32100369)